# Retrieving the name of an image

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a silly question perhaps but would like to know how to retrieve the name of an image.

for example

```
string name;
 Image imageOne = Image.FromFile("../../Images/PozeOne.jpg");
name = ?
```

Comment: images don't have names, do you mean filename that image is created from?

Comment: What do you mean by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Path.GetFilename

```
var path  = "../../Images/PozeOne.jpg";

Image imageOne = Image.FromFile(path);

string name = Path.GetFilename(path);
```

Comment: @SonerGönül I just needed to show him his own code. Didn't want it to be out of his context.

Answer (score 1):

```
    "PozeOne.jpg" is the name of image.... :-)
```

---

```
    string path="../../Images/PozeOne.jpg";
    string[] imageName=path.split('/');
    string image_Name_Is= imageName[imageName.Lenght-1];
```